# Performance of FileResultPath (Image path) in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, image

I have a Mvc Action which sends the **'FilePathResult'** for a 'jpeg' **image** as shown below.

```
public ActionResult GetImage()
        {
            string outputImagePath = Server.MapPath(@"Images/OutputImage.jpeg");
            return File(outputImagePath , "image/jpeg");
        }
```

Now this takes **significantly higher** time compared to referencing the Image path using the **direct Url**. The time taken is as shown below.

> http://WebSite/Controller/GetImage
>   takes 500ms
>
> http://WebSite/Images/OutputImage.jpeg
>   takes 10ms

Is this normal or I am missing something here?

**Update:** This is average time taken. I am using the following environment.

```
.Net 4, Asp.Net 2.0, IIS 7.5, Ninject
```

Comment: Is the measured time the first call to the action or subsequent calls?

Comment: I expected a small difference since static data handler is very quick but not this much. What IIS are u using?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not right. Without having all of the code it would be very difficult to say where the problem.

First of all I really doubt this much difference could be just because of caching but it make sense to have **output caching** on your Action. Static content handler does use output caching so this partly could be blamed for.

If that does not solve the issue, I suggest to put **tracing** in various aspects of the call, from controller creation (perhaps in constructor if you are not using custom controller factory) to action to before load the file, after loading the file and EndRequest. You can use Debug.WriteLine and then use DebugView to see how long every section took and this should help you find the bottleneck.